# Mock Sequel connections to Oracle database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to test a Rails application that connects to a remote Oracle database using the Sequel gem. Since the user needs to be logged in in order to use the site, I'm using WebMock. However, because WebMock stops all requests to outside sources, I get the error `Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: OCIError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener` every time I run my tests. How would I mock the database connection? Should I try something else instead?

I'm not sure what code to provide, so here are some snippets that may relate to possible solutions:

`database_connection.rb`:

```
class DatabaseConnection
  @@db = nil

  def self.get_db
    @@db ||= Sequel.connect(Settings.db.main.to_hash)
  end

  def self.db_query(query)
    get_db[query]
  end
end
```

In `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    stub_request(:post, "/path/to/third/party").
      with(:body => "request body").
      to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
  end

  # ... rest of the code
end
```

Relevant gems from `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'ruby-oci8', git: 'https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8.git'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'webmock' # 1.21.0
  gem 'capybara' # 2.4.4
end
```

Comment: I don't think you can mock the database connection since that's probably working off a TCP/IP socket connection without HTTP.  If you're wanting to mock the database, what's to stop you from just setting up an in-memory sqlite database locally that Sequel can talk to?  I think Sequel comes with that feature by default.  If that doesn't work, what you might want to do instead is mock the Sequel object itself by creating a class that can be put in place of Sequel but its methods would return objects that you'd expect.

Comment: Do you know any resources that would help me with the latter? I don't believe I can do the former.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot do the former?  ```Sequel.mock``` should provide a means of having a fake in-memory database to work with for testing purposes.  The latter is as simple as creating a class/module that has the same methods you'd be calling on Sequel but would return whatever your code expects.  You could even name it "Sequel", so long as you don't already have the real Sequel required in testing.  This will probably be WAY more work than simply using Sequel with a disposable testing database.   http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/Mock/Database.html

Answer (score 6):

Sequel ships with a mock adapter for exactly this purpose:

```
@@db ||= Sequel.connect('mock://oracle')
```

See the documentation for details about how to use the mocked database:

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/Mock/Database.html
http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/Mock/Dataset.html